# Nutch Hadoop Development with Eclipse/IntilliJ IDEA

Tags: java, hadoop, intellij-idea, solr, nutch

I am new to Nutch hadoop development. I have configured Hadoop 2.7.3, Nutch 1.12 integrated successfully with Solr 6.3. How do I develop customized crawling and data retrieval applications using IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ. (I prefer Intellij IDEA)?

I have beginner level skills with spark and hadoop development but stuck at this stage how to go for Nutch and solr with hadoop.

Comment: Can you specify what you trouble you are having? Simple crawling and indexing can be done following the Nutch tutorial: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

By the way, Nutch 1.12 does not support Solr 6.X. You may run into unexpected problems as I did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354313/apache-nutch-1-12-with-apache-solr-6-2-1-give-an-error/40460928#40460928

Thus, I suggest you to integrate Nutch 1.12 with Solr 5.X

Comment: I forgot to point out that Nutch 1.12 has a bug. I explained how to fix the bug :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354313/apache-nutch-1-12-with-apache-solr-6-2-1-give-an-error/40460928#40460928

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eclipse IDE to Develop Nutch Plugins. You will need to install subclipse, IvyDE and m2e plugins to Eclipse and then import Nutch Trunk project. In [this blog article](http://techsphot.com/running-nutch-in-eclipse/) I have explained the process in detail, with plugins development in the [next article](http://techsphot.com/nutch-plugins-introduction-and-development).